# Why isn't my auto-versioning in my winforms app not incrementing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple winforms app for testing auto-versioning which I specified in the AssemlyInfo.cs file under properties. How do I make it increment?

```
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

winform:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMessage.Text = Class1.HelloTest();


    string version = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion;
    this.Text = String.Format("My Application Version {0}", version);
}
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), that value comes from `AssemblyVersion`: "Typically, a version number displays as major number.minor number.build number.private part number. You can set it explicitly by setting the assembly version within your assembly manifest."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out 
`//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

Comment: That worked, but the version didn't start at 1.0.0.0? It was something like 1.0.7396.16020. Is that the way it's suppose to work?